# select2 selectall ajax loaded options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I want to implement select all feature in select2 in which option will be loaded from ajax call and select all will be called when the select all checkbox is checked. I have read most of forums but nothing works.

select2 code:

```
 $('.select2-channel').select2('destroy').val('').select2({
    placeholder: 'Select Channels',
    allowClear: true,
    closeOnSelect: false,
    width: '100%',
    // templateResult: formatChannel,
    ajax: {
        url: "/getChannnels",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        cache: false,
        data: function (params) {
                return {
                    search_term: params.term,
                    status : 1,
                    };
            },
        processResults: function(data, params) {
            console.log(data);
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) { return {id: item.id, text: item.name}})
                };
            }
        }
})
.on('select2:open', (e) => {
    // console.log(e);
    // $(".select2-results:not(:has(button.select2-channel-selectAll))").prepend('<div id="select2-channel-selectAll-div" style="padding-left: 5px;height: 30px;display: inline-table;"><button id="select2-channel-selectAll"  onclick="select2SelectAllChannels(this)" class="btn btn-outline-dark text-right select2-channel-selectAll">Select All</button></div>');
    $(".select2-results:not(:has(input.selectall_channels))").prepend(' <label class="pull-right"> <small>select all </small><input type="checkbox" class="selectall_channels" onChange="select2SelectAllChannels(this)"/></label>');

});
```

I have the the checkbox prepended in dropdown to implement select all and try to handle the checkbox on change event by function call. So I want to know the code to select all to write in side the checkbox change event function. Thankyou

Comment: Hi, can you make this runnable with dummy datas ?